# Remove point after domain name in nginx

Tags: redirect, web, nginx, dns

I have detected that my site is accessible using domain name with a point at the end. For example "sim-portal.ru.". It works well and I found this is a good form of domain name according to W3C. But I need this domain automatically redirected to normal domain (without point) for example "sim-portal.ru", because cookies don't work in "pointed" domain and links looks wrong. I've redirected www.-prefixed domain (like www.sim-portal.ru) to basic domain using next rule:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  www.sim-portal.ru;
    rewrite ^ http://sim-portal.ru$request_uri? permanent; #301 redirect
}
```

But same rule doesn't work for post-pointed domain:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  sim-portal.ru.;
    rewrite ^ http://sim-portal.ru$request_uri? permanent; #301 redirect
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I kinda don't understand, what's a post pointed domain ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady post-pointed means "having a point after it"... I am not native english speaker, so I just get this word from my mind...

Comment: does that even exist? `sim-portal.ru.something` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yes, but without "something". Just read the question carefully.

Comment: ok I tested it on my server and i found that it's a valid URL, didn't know that before, but I also noticed that when I access `http://example.com.` the access logs show that the requests hit the `/` location, so nginx doesn't really notice the `.` even though the network inspector shows that the `HOST` variable in the requests indeed had the `.` in it, strange if you ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a good solution by myself.
This rule added to both server {} blocks (either for www.sim-portal.ru and sim-portal.ru) will solve the issue:

```
if ($http_host != 'sim-portal.ru') {
    return 301 http://sim-portal.ru$request_uri;
}
```

But just don't forget to restart nginx!